# Horizontal News Scroller in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I think I would have gone through like a hundred websites but I do not seem to find the perfect horizontal news scroller for my website. My requirements are:

1) Must be smooth
2) Must scroll from right end of browser to left end (meaning 100% width)
3) Must be continuous (Meaning news-item-1 must be visible immediately after the last-news-item)
4) Must be light in weight.
5) Must pause on mouseover.

[liScroll](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html) is the closest that I could find. I can set 100% width and its motion is smooth unlike say an HTML marquee. It also pauses on mouseover. However it is extremely heavy and gets stuck in browsers like Firefox (works fine on Chrome). Also, I have to wait for 100% whitespace to scroll before I can see news-item-1 after the last-news-item).

I would really prefer if it were in jQuery since the rest of my scripts use jQuery although I am so desperate at this point that I am ready to use Mootools or Prototype or any other Javascript library out there. Is there any script out there that meets my requirements? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=seamless+marquee

Comment: NIIce one: http://cektkp.com/twittermarquee/twitmarquee.html

Comment: Twit Marquee is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html)? It does everything you've mentioned.